# i need it to return in a Time Format

Tags: c#, datetime, time

i need it to return in a time format EX 0:00:00

*method/function*

```
        public override DateTime OverallReadingTime()
        {
            return FinishTime.Subtract(StartTime);
        }
```

i understand the timespan but would like to know why this doesn't work

Comment: If your [read the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx) you will discover that DateTime.Subtract returns a TimeSpan not a DateTime.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean?  Are you talking about how you format the time for printing to a screen?

Comment: You want `TimeSpan`: `public TimeSpan OverallReadingTime => FinishTime - StartTime;`

Comment: The difference between two dates is not another date. Your override is totally wrong as well the base class you are overriding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Compile Error**

Your code won't compile because the `DateTime.Subtract(..)` function returns `TimeSpan` but your function requires a type of `DateTime`.

**Options**

- Continue using the overridden function and adapt it according to mattshu's answer.
- Create a new function that returns a `TimeSpan` type (see below).
- Create a new function that returns a `String` type (also see below).

**TimeSpan Option**

```
public TimeSpan OverallReadingTime()
{
    return FinishTime.Subtract(StartTime);
}
```

**String Option**

```
public string OverallReadingTime()
{
    return FinishTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString();
}
```

Comment: The difference between two dates is never another date. The only correct result is a TimeSpan. Thus the whole question is based on a wrong assumption. At least your answer is correct albeit you cannot override with a TimeSpan if the base class requires a DateTime as result.

Comment: I feel like the only one making false assumptions is you, sir. I am simply providing him with an option as to what could be since the OP has not given us enough context. So only he can make the final decision, I'm simply providing options to help him make that decision.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't understood my point. If the base class defines a method _OverallReadingTime_ as returning a _DateTime_, you cannot override it in the derived class returning a TimeSpan. This is the only point I want to underline in your question. Thus, while returning a TimeSpan is the only correct thing to do when you measure the difference between two dates, probably you should suggest the OP to change the base class definition to allow your override to work.

Comment: Well had you read the paragraph before the code example I stated this. I restructured my answer so that this issue was clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the format after subtracting

```
public override DateTime OverallReadingTime()
{
    return Convert.ToDateTime(FinishTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss"));
}
```

Comment: Minor correction:  `:` [has to be escaped or you'll get an `Input string was not in a correct format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#Other) error

Answer (score 0):

you should give further details to your problem. However, the solution is to use the overrwritten "-"-operator.

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = start.AddHours(2);
        Console.WriteLine((end - start));
```

Produces `02:00:00`,

which is your desired output? So change the return variable of your function to string and `return (FinishTime - StartTime).ToString();`